# Creating PDFs with Prawn - missing attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

I'm working on PDF creation in my rails application.  I found PDFkit didn't necessarily do what I wanted to do, so I figured I'd test out Prawn.

I added it to my controller using this code:

```
   def show
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = Prawn::Document.new(@document)
          send_data pdf.render, filename:"1",
                                type: "application/pdf",
                                disposition: "inline"
        end
     end  
  end
```

But using this I get a Missing Attribute error.  I'm assuming this is because my model is also named `Documents` and conflicts with the `Prawn::Document.new` command?

Can I just not have a `documents` model and use Prawn - or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's about `Document` vs `Prawn::Document`, but I've never seen someone pass an ActiveRecord instance to `Prawn::Document.new`. I think that expects an options hash, right? And calling `render` before giving it any content seems suspicious. What is the actual stack trace?

Comment: After reviewing the documentation it doesn't seem as simple as passing `@document` to Prawn.  Looks like you're right, I'd need to build from scratch like in RailsCast episode 153.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn-revised?autoplay=true .  But that's a little heavier that what I needed to do, so I think I'll look back into correcting my CSS issue with PDFkit